# In 2016, do we still need to use BouncyCastle to work around the Export Control Restrictions on Cryptography that US Government imposes?

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography

Many people use Bouncy Castle to use the wonderful implementations of the Java Cryptography API (JCA) for Ciphers, MessageDigests, etc. Many also use it to circumvent the Export Control Restrictions that US imposes on usage of cryptography with key lengths exceeding 128 bits.

However, I have read somewhere that in 2016, there were some changes in those restrictions that US Govt imposes. Can we stop using bouncy castle and switch to Native Java JCA Provider if that is the only reason why it is used in a project?

Can someone throw some light on this ?

Comment: I am not sure this question belongs to SO, but I would like to know the answer, too.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is more of a legal question than a programming question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. It's called Java 9. Try it. You can disable the export control *programmatically*.

Besides that, the Bouncy Castle provider *does not* circumvent the export control, only the lightweight API does. This is because the `Cipher` class contains the constraint, and all Service Provider Implementations (Spi's) are used through this class.

Comment: Can you confirm/clarify that "yes" applies to "Can we stop using bouncy castle", not "do we still need to use BouncyCastle" as in the question's title?